# Samba share for entire HDD with minimum security

Tags: linux, networking, virtualbox, network-shares, samba

My environment:

- VirtualBox running Linux Mint
- VirtualBox has two network adapters:

  - Adapter 1 = NAT (10.0.2.15 as enp0s3)
  - Adapter 2 = Host-only (192.168.56.101 as enp0s8)
- Host is running Windows 10

Want I want to achieve:

1. The Host should be able to access the entire VirtualBox HDD via Samba (on Host-only network interface) with minimum security (no password or restrictions if possible)
2. The VirtualBox should be able to access the outside network/internet on the NAT network interface, but deny any access to directories via this interface (which I think comes automatically with NAT anyway).

VirtualBox's ifconfig:

```
enp0s3    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:8b:1a:a4  
          inet addr:10.0.2.15  Bcast:10.0.2.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::abf3:b5bf:9f3a:b8c7/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:60866 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:15402 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:70878227 (70.8 MB)  TX bytes:1168864 (1.1 MB)

enp0s8    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:cd:c9:9a  
          inet addr:192.168.56.101  Bcast:192.168.56.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::b1d2:7dfd:4114:9257/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:161 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:134 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:21522 (21.5 KB)  TX bytes:20314 (20.3 KB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:407 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:407 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
          RX bytes:44489 (44.4 KB)  TX bytes:44489 (44.4 KB)
```

The Samba configuration:

```
[global]
    workgroup = WORKGROUP
    server string = %h server (Samba, Ubuntu)
   dns proxy = no
   interfaces = 127.0.0.0/8 enp0s8
   bind interfaces only = yes
   log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
   max log size = 1000
   syslog = 0
   panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d
   server role = standalone server
   passdb backend = tdbsam
   obey pam restrictions = yes
   unix password sync = yes
   passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd %u
   passwd chat = *Enter\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *Retype\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *password\supdated\ssuccessfully* .
   pam password change = yes
   map to guest = bad user

[root]
browseable = yes
path = /
guest ok = yes
read only = no
create mask = 0644
directory mask = 0755
force user = root
writable = yes
valid users = root
admin users = root
public = yes
```

The Samba user (pdbedit -L -v):

```
Unix username:        root
NT username:          
Account Flags:        [U          ]
User SID:             S-1-5-21-2575914641-1571404728-2205854153-1000
Primary Group SID:    S-1-5-21-2575914641-1571404728-2205854153-513
Full Name:            root
Home Directory:       \\mintbox\root
HomeDir Drive:        
Logon Script:         
Profile Path:         \\mintbox\root\profile
Domain:               MINTBOX
Account desc:         
Workstations:         
Munged dial:          
Logon time:           0
Logoff time:          Wed, 06 Feb 2036 17:06:39 SAST
Kickoff time:         Wed, 06 Feb 2036 17:06:39 SAST
Password last set:    Wed, 02 Nov 2016 20:40:47 SAST
Password can change:  Wed, 02 Nov 2016 20:40:47 SAST
Password must change: never
Last bad password   : 0
Bad password count  : 0
Logon hours         : FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
```

The Samba daemon status:

```
● smbd.service - LSB: start Samba SMB/CIFS daemon (smbd)
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/smbd; bad; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Thu 2016-11-03 08:01:06 SAST; 3min 26s ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 24631 ExecStop=/etc/init.d/smbd stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 24645 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/smbd start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Tasks: 3 (limit: 512)
   CGroup: /system.slice/smbd.service
           ├─24663 /usr/sbin/smbd -D
           ├─24664 /usr/sbin/smbd -D
           └─24666 /usr/sbin/smbd -D

Nov 03 08:01:06 MintBox systemd[1]: Starting LSB: start Samba SMB/CIFS daemon (smbd)...
Nov 03 08:01:06 MintBox smbd[24645]:  * Starting SMB/CIFS daemon smbd
Nov 03 08:01:06 MintBox smbd[24645]:    ...done.
Nov 03 08:01:06 MintBox systemd[1]: Started LSB: start Samba SMB/CIFS daemon (smbd).
```

The NMB daemon status:

```
● nmbd.service - LSB: start Samba NetBIOS nameserver (nmbd)
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/nmbd; bad; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Thu 2016-11-03 08:01:14 SAST; 4min 39s ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 24689 ExecStop=/etc/init.d/nmbd stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 24704 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/nmbd start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Tasks: 1 (limit: 512)
   CGroup: /system.slice/nmbd.service
           └─24724 /usr/sbin/nmbd -D

Nov 03 08:01:14 MintBox systemd[1]: Starting LSB: start Samba NetBIOS nameserver (nmbd)...
Nov 03 08:01:14 MintBox nmbd[24704]:  * Starting NetBIOS name server nmbd
Nov 03 08:01:14 MintBox nmbd[24704]:    ...done.
Nov 03 08:01:14 MintBox systemd[1]: Started LSB: start Samba NetBIOS nameserver (nmbd).
```

When I attempt to access the VirtualBox share from the Host (Windows 10) I get:

> Windows cannot access \\192.168.56.101

**QUESTION:** How should I configure Samba to allow full access to the entire HDD (root directory) with minimum security (no password or restrictions if possible)?

Answer (score 0):

In case someone wants to achieve the goal, this Samba configuration works for me:

```
    [global]
  workgroup = HOME
  server string = %h server (Samba, Ubuntu)
  dns proxy = no
  log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
  max log size = 1000
  syslog = 0
  panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d
  server role = standalone server
  security = user
  map to guest = Bad Password
  passdb backend = tdbsam
  obey pam restrictions = yes
  unix password sync = yes
  passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd %u
  passwd chat = *Enter\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *Retype\snew\s*\spassword:*        %n\n *password\supdated\ssuccessfully* .
  pam password change = yes
  usershare allow guests = yes

    [root]
    comment = Root directory
    path = /
    public = yes
    writable = yes
    available = yes
    browsable = yes
    guest ok = yes
    create mask = 0777
    directory mask = 0777
    force user = root
    force group = root
```

Also remember to add the "root" user as a Samba user:

```
sudo smbpasswd -a root
```